# Attribute IsDefined - Arithmetic overflow exception

Tags: c#

So I was looping through all properties of a class to see if there are any properties which have attribute X

So this was my code:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(Column))).ToArray();
```

The odd thing is this results in the following error: `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

How can a simple C# function like this result in an Overflow?

I've tried inspecting a few things in the immediate window and it doesn't result in anything odd either:

```
{Secret.Datasets.Wiki.Item Item}
    Attributes: None
    CanRead: false
    CanWrite: true
    CustomAttributes: Count = 0
    DeclaringType: {Name = "Tag" FullName = "Tag"}
    GetMethod: null
    IsSpecialName: false
    MemberType: Property
    MetadataToken: 385875972
    Module: {DynamicRestAssembly}
    Name: "Item"
    PropertyType: {Name = "Item" FullName = "Secret.Datasets.Wiki.Item"}
    ReflectedType: {Name = "Tag" FullName = "Tag"}
    SetMethod: {Secret.Datasets.Wiki.Item get_Item()}
```

And the attribute:

```
{Name = "Column" FullName = "Rest.Database.Attributes.Column"}
    Assembly: {Rest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "Rest.Database.Attributes.Column, Rest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    Attributes: Public | Sealed | BeforeFieldInit
    BaseType: {Name = "Attribute" FullName = "System.Attribute"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    CustomAttributes: Count = 1
    DeclaredConstructors: {System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo[1]}
    DeclaredEvents: {System.Reflection.EventInfo[0]}
    DeclaredFields: {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[4]}
    DeclaredMembers: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[13]}
    DeclaredMethods: {System.Reflection.MethodInfo[4]}
    DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.<get_DeclaredNestedTypes>d__23}
    DeclaredProperties: {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[4]}
    DeclaringMethod: '((System.RuntimeType)(typeof(Column))).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: null
    FullName: "Rest.Database.Attributes.Column"
    GUID: {0f891941-d2ca-3a57-b5cc-054d94ec41f2}
    GenericParameterAttributes: '((System.RuntimeType)(typeof(Column))).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: '((System.RuntimeType)(typeof(Column))).GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[0]}
    GenericTypeParameters: {System.Type[0]}
    HasElementType: false
    ImplementedInterfaces: {System.Type[1]}
    IsAbstract: false
    IsAnsiClass: true
    IsArray: false
    IsAutoClass: false
    IsAutoLayout: true
    IsByRef: false
    IsCOMObject: false
    IsClass: true
    IsConstructedGenericType: false
    IsContextful: false
    IsEnum: false
    IsExplicitLayout: false
    IsGenericParameter: false
    IsGenericType: false
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    IsImport: false
    IsInterface: false
    IsLayoutSequential: false
    IsMarshalByRef: false
    IsNested: false
    IsNestedAssembly: false
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
    IsNestedFamORAssem: false
    IsNestedFamily: false
    IsNestedPrivate: false
    IsNestedPublic: false
    IsNotPublic: false
    IsPointer: false
    IsPrimitive: false
    IsPublic: true
    IsSealed: true
    IsSecurityCritical: true
    IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
    IsSecurityTransparent: false
    IsSerializable: false
    IsSpecialName: false
    IsUnicodeClass: false
    IsValueType: false
    IsVisible: true
    MemberType: TypeInfo
    MetadataToken: 33554466
    Module (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {Rest.dll}
    Module: {Rest.dll}
    Name: "Column"
    Namespace: "Rest.Database.Attributes"
    ReflectedType: null
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: null
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "Column" FullName = "Rest.Database.Attributes.Column"}
```

Can anyone explain why this is resulting in an overflow exception?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT1: Even this results in a Arithmetic overflow `x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Column)).Any()`

EDIT2: Pastebin https://pastebin.com/raw/LQDmvU7J

EDIT3: TypeBuilder Code

```
    foreach (Type type in RestServer.CallerAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (!typeof(IDataSet).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface && type != typeof(DataSet<>) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        TypeBuilder builder = Builder.GetTypeBuilder(type.Name, type);
        Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

        type.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Relation), false).Length > 0)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => properties.Add(OverrideRelation(x, ref builder, type), x));

        BuildClassTypes(builder, properties, type);
    }
```

I recreate the exact same class and create the new Type.
In this part `OverrideRelation` I add a new property, and while I'm typing this I'm hitting myself since I think this is what is giving my errors....

```
            MethodBuilder propertyGetBuilder = builder.DefineMethod
            (
                dynamicFunctionName,
                MethodAttributes.Public,
                propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                Type.EmptyTypes
            );

            ILGenerator propertyGetIlGenerator = propertyGetBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            propertyGetIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            propertyGetIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyInfo.Name);
            propertyGetIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, relationKeyField.Name);
            propertyGetIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, relationAttribute.RelationColumn);
            propertyGetIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, loadRelationMethod);

            propertyGetIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            PropertyBuilder newProperty = builder.DefineProperty
            (
                propertyInfo.Name, 
                propertyInfo.Attributes, 
                propertyInfo.PropertyType, null
            );

            newProperty.SetSetMethod(propertyGetBuilder);
```

Comment: What type are you checking the properties of?  Show us its complete definition.  Does it somehow inherit from itself?

Comment: It's quite a big class, let me get it in a pastebin for you

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/LQDmvU7J

Comment: Okay, your class has only the one property, maybe a second that I overlooked.  I suspect this is happening because your class has an inheritance relationship involving itself:  `class DataSet<T> : IDataSet where T : DataSet<T>, new()`.  Add your class to the question without its functions, those aren't relevant.

Comment: If it's a big class, you are obligated to pare it down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Amy Correct only one static property. The odd thing is. It worked before I had the nested generic dependencies. What might be an issue though is that my class is being generated via a TypeBuilder. But I still don't know how this could break the Attributes functions.

Comment: If you pass `false` as the third parameter to `Attribute.IsDefined`, does it still overflow?  I'm guessing the self-referencing inheritance relationship is causing an infinite loop in something like `MetadataImport.Enum` or `CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributeRecords`, resulting in the loop variable overflowing.

Comment: If you think that might be an issue, please include that in the question.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach Okay the false fixes the overflow exception so there is some sort of loop. How odd. I'll try to get my Typebuilder Code here in a second.

Comment: @Amy Will do, hang on.

Comment: Adding `false` lends credence to my hypothesis.  So basically its following the inheritance hierarchy until it overflows.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: @Amy there is no cyclic inheritance, there is a cyclic generic type parameter constraint. Cyclic inheritance is disallowed in C#.

Comment: @InBetween i'm open to other ideas.  That's the best I can come up with.  Do you have a better hypothesis?

Comment: @Amy Its not about ideas, `DataSet<T>` has no "inheritance relationship involving itself", thats a fact. It has a cyclic constraint on `T` which is a completely different animal. I am not saying that isn't be part of the issue, I haven't looked into it in depth.